# WEB2PY: Displaying data from DB with JOIN but with some condition

Tags: join, logic, conditional-statements, web2py

I am having trouble with some logic.

1. I have 3 tables: `db.service_request`, `db.technician` and `db.assigned`
2. Many `Service Request` can be assigned to a `Technician`
3. The table `db.assigned` is where all assigned `service_request`are saved together with the `Technician`'s ID
4. Now I want to display all data in `service_request` EXCEPT for the `service_request` that was not assigned to the current logged In `Technician`

How someone please tell me how to make this work ?

What I have is this, I get all `service request` that has been `assigned` to the current logged in `Technician`, but does not get all the other `service request` that has not yet been `assigned`.

```
query=db.service_request.id==db.assigns.sr_id
query2=db.assigns.technician==user_id
query4=((query)&(query2))
get_assigned=db(query4).select(orderby=~db.service_request.date_time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [left outer join](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Left-outer-join) and specify the condition that either `db.assigned.technician` matches the current user or there is no matching record in `db.assigned`:

```
left_join = db.assigned.on(db.service_request.id == db.assigned.sr_id)
current_user_assigned = db.assigned.technician == user_id
request_not_assigned = db.assigned.id == None
rev_request_time = ~db.service_request.date_time
rows = db(current_user_assigned | request_not_assigned).select(left=left_join,
                                                               orderby=rev_request_time)
```